# Could filter Failed does not include Disabled case that failed before?

Tags: testrigor

Currently testRigor filter by test cases state Failed returns eighter Failed and Disabled:

[image: snapshot]

Could filter show only Failed cases?

Answer (score 0):

testRigor filters for failed test cases no longer included disabled cases. Disabled test cases are now separated by their own filter.